# Way to patch pinhole size hole in black pvc drain/vent pipe

Tags: plumbing, pipe, pvc

I accidentally drilled through my drain/pvc pipe while installing baseboard. It was right behind the drywall. I used trim screws and it barely went through. There is a pinhole size hole from what I can see. It is on the upstairs floor and the positioning of the hole is above the toilet and bathtub level. So, I am fairly sure, no water goes through that pipe and it is a vent pipe. I flushed a bunch and did not see water coming out.

My question is, I still want to patch it. What material is best to patch black pvc pipe? Silicone or something else?

Because of where the whole is I can cut part of the drywall in the place where the baseboard will go so I have a bit of space to work a one to two fingers through the hole.

Answer (score 1):

get a black pvc coupler for the same sized pipe, cut it so you have a piece that will snap over the existing pipe and have good coverage either side of the hole. Glue that sucker in place and call it done.

Comment: That would work if I had space but they put the pipe right behind the drywall. It is definitely a vent not a drain. The bathtub and toilet right next to it drains under the floor. Hence I why I though maybe some silicone or putty may cut it.

Comment: so tight theres not room for the wall thickness of the coupler? ouch!

Comment: Get PVC compatible epoxy and call it a day. If it's really a vent then you don't need to worry a whole lot about it.

Comment: Well I flushed a ton of water on everything and I can hear it drain but no water is coming out. There is nothing that can drain water above the floor, so pretty much a vent. Goes straight to the attic on onto the roof.

Comment: The drain is ABS. I found a silicone for it, Loctile brand. I wonder if that works better than epoxy.

Comment: @Michael  I would use epoxy over silicone, silicones are great at first but with age will pull away.  With this behind a wall and not easily accessible the epoxy would be better.

Answer (score 1):

ABS dissolves in acetone. Using a glass or polypropylene container, dissolve in acetone as much ABS as it will absorb. You then have a "welding solution" which you can apply to the pinhole on the pipe. Apply a reasonably thick layer and let it cure/dry overnight. Some nail polish removers are acetone based. Those that are not will be labeled as such. Avoid additives if you go this route. For the risk averse, acetone is considered a hazardous substance. Read and follow all label directions. Another source of this solvent is ABS cement, available at many DIY / home repair merchants.

Apply one or two more layers and you'll have a truly permanent repair.

I used the above method to solvent-weld pieces of an ABS 3D printed boat hull model. A couple of the pieces were semi-failures in the print mode, but the plastic was intact. Using the solvent-weld method, the cured seam between the two was as strong or stronger than the rest of the model part. I was unable to break them.

For your pinhole, you won't need such structural strength, but you can be certain of a permanent seal.